# userscript for getting rid of annoying notifications counter on title of pages like Facebook, Linkedin, etc

Tags: javascript, notifications, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to do a userscript rid of annoying notifications counter on title of pages like Facebook, Linkedin, etc.

Firstly I tried to use the extension "Rename Tab Title" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rename-tab-title/kppndhfiaenbiioipolacicknfmdcdep with my configuration described in the Support tab of that page, in the comment of user Sérgio Loureiro. But had no success.

What I mean is the "(1) " thing before the page title, that will be rendered on the respective tab. In this case I was doing it for the Vivaldi browser, that supports user script from the base, without any extension. I think this is also available for other browsers via tampermonkey or greasemonkey.

An example:

[image]

So I wrote an `*.user.js` file with the contents:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://*/*
// @match https://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    document.title = document.title.replace(/^\(.*\) /, '');

    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const targetNode = document.getElementById('title');

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { characterData: true };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = function(mutationsList, observer)
    {
        // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
        for(const mutation of mutationsList)
        {
            document.title = document.title.replace(/^\(.*\) /, '');
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
})();
```

and followed the process on https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/66719/userscript-installation to get it added to the browser as an extension, but I continue to see this distracting counter. ☹️

So, my question, as a very lay person on javascript and user scripts is: What am I doing wrong?

I've wrote the mutation observer handler to catch when the server page is trying to change the page title out of a page load request operation, but it seems to me it is not working.

Comment: `document.getElementById('title')` should be `document.querySelector('title')`.

Comment: @double-beep: Tried that. Did not solve. Was it only an off-topic side note?

Comment: You tried it, but didn't update your code. `new MutationObserver(mut => console.log(mut[0].target)).observe(document.querySelector('title'), { subtree: true, characterData: true, childList: true });` should log the `title` element when it changes.

Comment: @double-beep: I am in doubt what mutations should I observe. Given the `<title>SOME TITLE</title>` has only string data inside it, isn't `characterData` the only thing I need to observe?

Comment: @double-beep: Thanks. I answered my own question using your advice.

Comment: Related question on Web Applications SE: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106404/113181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derived from my own tests and @cactus12 experiences, here is a user script that seems to work.

One needs to follow the process in https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/66719/userscript-installation
using a script like the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://*/*
// @match https://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    function cleanTitle()
    {
        const regex = /^\(.*\) /;

        if(document.title.match(regex) != null)
            document.title = document.title.replace(regex, '');
    }

    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const titleNode = document.querySelector('title');

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { childList: true };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(cleanTitle);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(titleNode, config);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    cleanTitle();   //initial clean
})();
```

Comment: I find your script cleaner than another one I found in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/viswanathgs/72042a6827f557c2c3137e3d49a9113f). However, the author of that script added `observer.disconnect();` to "Pause observer to avoid possible infinite recursion". Do you find that a useful addition?

Comment: In addition, inspired in the solution linked above, I'd suggest `\d+` followed by `\s+` for more accurate matching that avoids some false positives.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have a possible working solution, but there are a few things that could be improved. Here is my solution:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove Tab Title Notifciation Counters
// @version      0.5
// @description  Removes webpage notification counters that appear at the begining of the tab title. Ex.) "(1) Example Title" becomes "Example Title"
// @author       nomadic
// @match        http://*/*
// @match        https://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  function cleanTitleText() {
    let title = document.title;
    const regex = /^\(.*\) /;
    const hasNotificationCounter = regex.test(title);

    if (hasNotificationCounter) {
      document.title = title.replace(regex, "");
    }
  }

  // observe changes in the webpage's title
  const targetElement = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
  const configurationOptions = { childList: true };
  const observer = new MutationObserver(cleanTitleText);
  observer.observe(targetElement, configurationOptions);

  // perform an initial cleaning on load
  cleanTitleText();
})();
```

### Notes on your solution:

It can be helpful to define variable and create functions to help avoid confusion and repeating yourself. If you name them well, you can also almost get away with not writing comments as they explain themselves.

> I also had to make a .match check before the replace, because some sites were becoming unresponsive.

I do a similar check with `.test()`. Otherwise you can end up in an infinite loop because it keeps changing the title and triggering another mutation.

> ```
> const callback = function(mutationsList, observer)
>     {
>         // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
>         for(const mutation of mutationsList)
>         {
> ```

In this case you don't really care what mutation event is triggering the callback function. You only really need to loop through the mutations if you are observing multiple different aspects of an element and performing different actions based on the type of mutation.

> ```
> const config = { subtree: true, characterData: true, childList: true};
> ```

When the title text is changed, it is actually the `childList` mutation that is detected. That means the `subtree` and `characterData` are unneeded.

---

Hope the notes help some! -nomadic from the Vivaldi Forums

Comment: Notes on your notes: I usually do write code more carefully, giving attention to details like DRY, good naming of variables, etc. ; for this case in particular, I really only needed a quick n' dirty solution that works. The problem of my solution was the observer was not attentive to the right thing, which is the `childList`. Thanks.

Comment: This is my current version of the algorithm: https://kopy.io/dGqET

Comment: Does it still work for you if you remove `subtree` and `characterData` from the `config`? When I tested it, it seemed to work with only including `childList: true`.

Comment: Yes it works, tks. My answer is below. I would now like to extend this to also get rid of the favicon badges, like the red dot of linkedin.

Comment: This is my try to also eliminate the red dot over the Linkedin favicon: https://kopy.io/gMu6y . My original idea was to restore the icon to a version without the red badge; but. for testing I decided to try removing the icon entries, just to see if the observer is working. The relevant part is under the `//-----ICON-----` comment. I was expecting to get a 'handling the ico' message on the console log, but unfortunately I did not.

Comment: Didn't test the code, but it looked like there were a few things wrong with the mutation observer. Try this: https://kopy.io/HWjh8

Answer (score 0):

I think I have succeeded, following @double-beep's advice of watching not only for `characterData`.

This is the script I have now. I also had to make a `.match` check before the replace, because some sites were becoming unresponsive.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://*/*
// @match https://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    if(document.title.match(/^\(.*\) /) != null)
    {
        document.title = document.title.replace(/^\(.*\) /, '');
    }

    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const targetNode = document.querySelector('title');

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { subtree: true, characterData: true, childList: true };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = function(mutationsList, observer)
    {
        // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
        for(const mutation of mutationsList)
        {
            if(document.title.match(/^\(.*\) /) != null)
            {
                document.title = document.title.replace(/^\(.*\) /, '');
            }   
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
})();
```

If someone sees a problem on the presented code, please tell me; I am not a lectured guy in javascript and even less in user scripts.

Comment: after some digging, I discovered that the title assignment of `document.title` is not just a string replacement, but a complete override of the title element by a new one, so it is why observing for `characterData` was not working at all.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text